# Trying to replace an item in a list with another item

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace an item in a list not necessarily at the end, just the position of the original item, then have it require the new item when it's asking you for your password. I'm kind of new to Python.

```
passwords = ['mrjoebblock' , 'mrjoefblock' , 'mrjoegblock', 'mrjoeadmin' ]
if choice == '3':
        password = raw_input('Welcome admin! I\'m going to need your password ')
        if password == 'mrjoeadmin':
            print('Welcome Mr. Joe!')
            Choice11 = raw_input('What would you like to do? Press 1 for changing your admin password, 2 for viewing a class\'s comments, or 3 for changing a class\'s password')
            if Choice11 == '1':
                print('You have chosen to change your password! ')
                Choice12 = raw_input('You will need to put in your current password to access this feature ')
                if Choice12 == 'mrjoeadmin':
                    Choice13 = raw_input('What would you like to change your password to? ')
                    passwords.remove('mrjoeadmin')
                    passwords.append(Choice13)
                    print('Thank you! Password has been changed. Log in with new password next time')
                    break
            if Choice11 == '2':
                print('you have chosen to view a class\'s comments!')
                Choice14 = raw_input('Which block would you like to view?')
                if Choice14 == 'F block':
                    print('To view F block\'s comments, go to where you search for things in your computer, and search CommentsFblock.txt. Open it')
                    time.sleep(10)
                    break
                if Choice14 == 'G block':
                    print('To view G block\'s comments, go to where you search for things in your computer, and search CommentsGblock.txt. Open it')
                    time.sleep(10)
                    break
                if Choice14 == 'B block':
                    print('To view B block\'s comments, go to where you search for things in your computer, and search CommentsBblock.txt. Open it')
                    time.sleep(10)
                    break
                else:
                    print('I\'m sorry, that\'s not a valid block name.')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    break
            if Choice11 == '3':
                print('you have chosen to change a block\'s password.')
                Choice15 = raw_input('Which block\'s password would you like to change?')
                if Choice15 == 'F block':
                    Choice16 = raw_input('You will need to put in your current password to change F block\'s password ')
                    if Choice16 == 'mrjoeadmin':
                        Choice17 = raw_input('What would you like to change F block\'s password to? ')
                        passwords.remove('mrjoefblock')
                        passwords.append(Choice17)
                        print('Thank you! Password has been changed. Remember to tell students the password has been changed')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        break
                if Choice15 == 'G block':
                    Choice18 = raw_input('You will need to put in your current password to change G block\'s password ')
                    if Choice18 == 'mrjoeadmin':
                        Choice19 = raw_input('What would you like to change G block\'s password to? ')
                        passwords.remove('mrjoegblock')
                        passwords.append(Choice19)
                        print('Thank you! Password has been changed. Remember to tell students the password has been changed')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        break
                if Choice15 == 'B block':
                    Choice20 = raw_input('You will need to put in your current password to change B block\'s password ')
                    if Choice20 == 'mrjoeadmin':
                        Choice21 = raw_input('What would you like to change B block\'s password to? ')
                        passwords.remove('mrjoebblock')
                        passwords.append(Choice21)
                        print('Thank you! Password has been changed. Remember to tell students the password has been changed')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        break
```

Comment: Then, what's your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to make it require the new password after you change it

Comment: @KraeganEpsilon Gotcha. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To replace an item in a list, simply assign it by its list position:

```
mylist = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'goodnight']

mylist[2] = 'good day'
```

Comment: thanks, but how would I make it require the password the next time the person tries to log in? would it be like:       if password = passwords[4] for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value of the element in the list (let's say you're going to change F Block's password, `'mrjoefblock'`), you can use a [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) function to return its index, just like that:

```
In [1]: passwords = ['mrjoebblock' , 'mrjoefblock' , 'mrjoegblock', 'mrjoeadmin' ]

In [2]: passwords.index('mrjoefblock')
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: passwords[passwords.index('mrjoefblock')] = 'newjoefblock'

In [4]: passwords
Out[4]: ['mrjoebblock', 'newjoefblock', 'mrjoegblock', 'mrjoeadmin']
```

This way you'll be able to update the password and keep in on the same position (if that's what you're asking).

But it seems strange to me to change passwords like that. I'd make it not a list, but a dictionary instead:

```
In [1]: credentials = {
   ...:     'B Block': 'mrjoebblock',
   ...:     'F Block': 'mrjoefblock',
   ...:     'G Block': 'mrjoegblock',
   ...:     'Admin': 'mrjoeadmin'
   ...: }
```

We can now find all the users with the given password:

```
In [2]: [user for user, password in credentials.iteritems() if password == 'mrjoeadmin']
Out[2]: ['Admin']
```

And change the password for any user rather easily:

```
In [3]: credentials['F Block'] = 'newjoefblock'

In [4]: credentials
Out[4]:
{'Admin': 'mrjoeadmin',
 'B Block': 'mrjoebblock',
 'F Block': 'newjoefblock',
 'G Block': 'mrjoegblock'}
```

---

Sorry, it was initially unclear what you're asking.

I came up with this simple example:

```
def login():
    """
    This function asks for the password and returns either the username (if logged in successfully)
    or False (if the password was incorrect).
    """
    password = raw_input("Password: ")

    if password == 'admin':
        return 'Administrator'
    elif password == 'ggguest':
        return 'Guest'
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We'll introduce a new variable which will be either a logged in user's name
    # or False (based on login()'s function result)
    user_logged_in = login()

    while True:  # An endless loop
        if user_logged_in:
            # the login() function didn't return False, so we're logged in!
            print "Yay! You're now logged in as {0}!".format(user_logged_in)

            # Here we'll do whatever you need to. 
            # I kept the example simple so it just asks if the user wants to log out. 
            # You can change the user's password here and ask for the password again.

            want_to_logout = raw_input("Want to log out? [y/n]: ")

            if want_to_logout == 'y':
                user_logged_in = login()  # Ask for the password again
            else:
                print 'Alright then! Do your thing!'
                break  # Break out of loop and continue
        else:
            # wrong password, ask again
            print "Wrong password :("
            user_logged_in = login()  # Ask for the password again

    print "Keep up the good job, {0}!".format(user_logged_in)
```

And here's how it's working:

```
$ python admin.py
Password: wrong_password
Wrong password :(
Password: admin
Yay! You're now logged in as Administrator!
Want to log out? [y/n]: y
Password: ggguest
Yay! You're now logged in as Guest!
Want to log out? [y/n]: n
Alright then! Do your thing!
Keep up the good job, Guest!
```

This way you could keep asking the user for the password if needed and continue otherwise.